# Wrapper function for passing in common configuration to another function

Tags: javascript

I'd like to make a wrapper function to apply some common configuration argument to different functions, but I am not sure how to get the `var config` added to the `fn` function.  Here is my code so far:

```js
function addConfig(val, fn) {
  var config = { value: val };
  
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.push(config);
    return fn.apply(this, args)
  }
}

function test(id, name, config) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

addConfig('a', test(1, 'bill')); // Does not log out config object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong. You must call the function returned by `addConfig` instead of `test`:

```js
function addConfig(val, fn) {
  var config = { value: val };
  return function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.push(config);
    return fn.apply(this, args)
  }
}

function test(id, name, config) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

addConfig('a', test)(1, 'bill');
```